# how to know when the DOM of an iFrame is ready again after changing its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox addon using jquery. I added an iFrame to a page and filled it with another page (allowed due same orign policy).

```
$('#globalContainer').append('<iframe id="reusable_iframe" src="" width="90%" height="400" name="reusable_iframe"></iframe>');
//....
$('#reusable_iframe').attr('src', link);
//...
var link = $('#reusable_iframe').contents().find(HTMLclass).eq(position).find(searchBy).attr('href');
```

The problem is, the DOM inside the iFrame isn't finished loading before my access. However, when I add an alert then it works without any problems:

```
$('#globalContainer').append('<iframe id="reusable_iframe" src="" width="90%" height="400" name="reusable_iframe"></iframe>');
//....
$('#reusable_iframe').attr('src', link);
//...
alert("wait a sec"); //<-------------------------
var link = $('#reusable_iframe').contents().find(HTMLclass).eq(position).find(searchBy).attr('href');
```

This problem is very similar to my ajax-problem, which also worked with an alert. [how to know when the DOM is ready again after adding a node from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712918/how-to-know-when-the-dom-is-ready-again-after-adding-a-node-from-ajax) I haven't found a solution for both problems...

I tried this one: [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe?answertab=active#tab-top) but it wasn't working for me...

Thank you all =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#globalContainer').append('<iframe id="reusable_iframe" src="" width="90%" height="400" name="reusable_iframe"></iframe>');
//....
$('#reusable_iframe').attr('src', link);

$('#reusable_iframe').load(function(){
    var link = $('#reusable_iframe').contents().find(HTMLclass).eq(position).find(searchBy).attr('href');

});
```

Comment: As I already told, this solution isn't working for me. The `.load()` seems never to fire. It's a facebook-page and I guess because all the ajax-requests (for chat) the site is never really finished loading. Any other solutions?

Comment: try rearranging the order of the three things