# how to add a jquery plugi for firefox-extension-developlment using add-on builder

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a firefox extension and want to solve this problem: [how to know when the DOM of an iFrame is ready again after changing its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742620/how-to-know-when-the-dom-of-an-iframe-is-ready-again-after-changing-its-content) 
I found
[this Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/chamilo/source/browse/main/inc/lib/javascript/jquery.frameready.js?repo=classic&r=39a2ef8dd8332b3680a10b24c922d8676c991aeb) which probably will solve my problem. But I don't know how to add this in my add-builder.

My problem is here:

```
/************************************************************
            You must specify the path to your jquery.js file below! 
    *************************************************************/

    var jQueryPath = "/main/inc/lib/javascript/jquery.js";
```

the path for the jquery.js is different for every user because it's inside the firefox context, for example:

> C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\im0woiy2.default\flightdeck\resources\jid0-rxgsbnpfxdmtfgdq504rka9xktm-at-jetpack-privatsphaere_tool-data\jquery-1.6.4.js

so how can I add this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You use the [`self` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/addon-kit/docs/self.html) of the add-on SDK:

```
var {data} = require("self");
var jQueryPath = data.url("jquery.js");
```

And you put `jquery.js` into the `data/` directory of your add-on.

Comment: i can't use this inside of a content script, can I? `Error: uncaught exception: ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @Weedjo: No, you cannot and you should not. When you call `PageMod()` you should simply specify `contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("myContentScript.js")]` - you can load more than one script file as content script.

Comment: I knew that already, but how can I put the path into the plugin where I need it?

Comment: @Weedjo: Use `postMessage()` to send it from your add-on to the content script.

Comment: @Weedjo Since the value isn't going to change, another option (cleaner than postMessage()) is to use contentScriptOptions.  There is an example on this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848890/684852

Comment: @SeanColombo: That's a question from 2011 - `contentScriptOptions` weren't introduced before Add-on SDK 1.8 (in June 2012).

Comment: @WladimirPalant ah, cool :) well, now there here so I'm glad we got a chance to add them to this page (since this is still the top result in Google for this problem).  Thanks for the original solution!