# Don't know what $.post is returning

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jeditable

**EDIT**:

I'm getting the object `{"readyState":1}`. Why is that? How can I return the result from the $.post (i.e. the object `{"result":"ERROR"}`).

---

Using jEditable. (Note: I think this is a simple jQuery question as opposed to a specific plugin question.)

I would like to see if a unique tag symbol already exists in the database. As such, I do a $.post on `onsubmit` and get a JSON object returned `{"result":"ERROR"}` (I know this using firebug).

My problem is I'm having trouble handling the data returned. When I do `alert(returned)` I just get a `Object object` response and not "TEST".

Any tips on what's wrong or how to find out what's going wrong?

CODE

```
//Edit Tag Symbol
$(".edittagsymbol").editable('myURL',{
    onsubmit : function(settings, td){
        var id =  $(this).attr('id');
        var input = $(td).find('input');
        var original = input.val();
        var returned = $.post('myURL',{"text": original}, 
                                function(data) {
                                    if (data.result == 'ERROR'){
                                        return data.result;
                                    }
                                },
                                "json"
                            );
        alert(returned);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.post` does not return the value returned from the passed function. It returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object) instead.

If you want to do something with your data, you should use a callback function.

A useful example is in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712918/how-to-know-when-the-dom-is-ready-again-after-adding-a-node-from-ajax).

Answer (score 1):

use `alert(JSON.stringify(returned))` to see what is the error. Because you expect JSON from server

Comment: Ahh that's the function I was looking for.

Comment: I'm getting the object `{"readyState":1}`. Why is that? Ho can I return the object `{"result":"ERROR"}`.

Comment: It means that u got an error while doing the operation u should get "readyState":2 I guess. But I dont know what is the problem maybe at server side of code..